# Laravel разграничение прав пользователей

Tags: laravel, авторизация, доступ, acl

Делаю проект на Laravel. Необходимо разграничить доступ к различным объектам моделей для разных пользователей по типу acl. Т.е. у одного пользователя может быть доступ к чтению/редактированию нескольких моделей. Например Вася и Петя могут редактировать post с id = 10, а Лена только просматривать.

Подскажите, можно в торону чего смотреть?

Comment: Ну обычно права привязывают не ка записям, а к модели. Т.е пользователи могут либо читать либо редактировать посты, а не конкретный пост. Я использую https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Comment: Задача как раз в том, чтобы привязывать права к конкретным записям.